# Give a recurrence relation for the population of fish after $n$ months.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

A lake initially contains 1000 fish. Suppose that in the absence of predators or other causes of removal, the fish population increases by 10% each month. However, factoring in all causes, 80 fish are lost each month.\

Give a recurrence relation for the population of fish after $n$ months. How many fish are there after 5 months? If your fish model predicts a non-integer number of fish, round down to the next lower integer.

Having a serious issue with recursive algorithms, can anyone please help me answer this?

Comment: Would it just be: n1 = 1000,     n2 = (n1)(1.1) - 80,      n3 =  n2(1.1) - 80,      n4 = n3(1.1) - 80,     n5 = n4(1.1) - 80  . Or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe your answer is correct.

Comment: $a_{1} = 1000$\\
    $a_{2} =\lfloor 1000(1.1) - 80\rfloor = 1020$\\
    $a_{3} =\lfloor 1020(1.1) - 80\rfloor = 1042$\\
    $a_{4} =\lfloor 1042(1.1) - 80\rfloor = 1066$\\
    $a_{5} =\lfloor 1066(1.1) - 80\rfloor = 1092$\\
    $a_{n} =\lfloor a_{n-1}(1.1) - 80\rfloor$  This is what I have now, I feel like it is right  If someone could confirm I  am on the right track that would be great

Comment: @Twizted13 You should add your attempts in to the question, otherwise it may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting population is $a_0 = 1000$. Each month we have an increase of $10\%$, and each month can be represented as $a_{n-1}$. We will loose $80$ fish each month. Putting all the information together, the recurrence relation will look like: $$a_n = \lfloor a_{n-1} \cdot 1.1 - 80 \rfloor$$

We put floor on this to round it down to the closest integer.

$$a_5 = 1121$$